# Can't use progressbar33 package

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to show the download progress but I can't get it to work as expected,
here is my code

```
import requests
from progressbar import Bar, ETA, FileTransferSpeed, ProgressBar


link = video_mp4_link
file_name = "download.mp4"

with open(file_name, "wb") as f:
    print("Downloading {}".format(file_name))
    response = requests.get(link, stream=True)
    total_length = int(response.headers.get('content-length'))

    widgets = ['[Downlaoding] ', Percentage(), ' ', Bar(),
            ' ', ETA(), ' ', FileTransferSpeed()]

    pbar = ProgressBar(widgets=widgets, maxval=total_length).start()
    for data in response.iter_content(chunk_size=4096):
        f.write(data)
        done = int(os.path.getsize('Tree_Scraper.py'))
        pbar.update(done)
    pbar.finish()
```

while downloading the file it shows the progress like this:

`[Downloading] 0% |                             | ETA: 35 days, 3:50:24 600 B/s`
the progress bar is stuck on 0%, ETA is 35~100 days and download speed is
B/s!!

after downloading the file, the progress is like this:

`[Downlaoding] 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:24 257.23 kB/s`

packages used:
    progressbar33
    requests

So what's going on?